# webview state restoring issues on changing the Activity android

Tags: android, webview

In my `webview` , I am loading an external link.

When I click on the registration button in `webview page` and start another activity (by button in `Activity`)and again come back to the Webview Activity , it load the `start link` again , not shows me registration page.

```
@Override
      protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
      {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        // Save the state of the WebView
        webView_page_load.saveState(outState);
      }

      @Override
      protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
      {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        // Restore the state of the WebView
        webView_page_load.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
      }
```

in onCreate

```
if (savedInstanceState==null) {
            webView_page_load .loadUrl("http://www.diamondworld.net/moblogin.aspx");
        }
```

onResume

@Override

```
protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        if (webViewBundle == null) {
             Log.e("webViewBundle", "karjeevwebViewBundle if "+webViewBundle);
            webView_page_load.loadUrl("http://www.diamondworld.net/moblogin.aspx");
        } else {
            webView_page_load.restoreState(webViewBundle);
             Log.e("webViewBundle", "karjeevwebViewBundle else "+webViewBundle);
        }
    }
```

Comment: check this http://www.lucazanini.eu/2013/android/how-to-save-the-state-of-a-webview-inside-a-fragment-of-an-action-bar/?lang=en/&lang=en

Comment: not working bro ... when i launch ( not pressed back button )to WebViewActivity it loads the sart link ..

Comment: try restoring it in on resume if you are using an activity.

Comment: still not working bro .. see my onResume code

Comment: Where are you saving the state. onSaveInstanceState?. there is no guarantee that everytime onSaveInstanceState will be called. try saving the state in onPause.

Comment: yes , I am doing it in onPause() only ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73068/discussion-between-khubaib-and-karthik-kolanji).

Comment: show me your onPause() code